# qt qtableWidget get current displayed range

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

It is possible to get the current range of columns / rows currently displayed ?

I don't mean the current selected range (which is easy to get), but the current visible range on the screen.

I tried, for the vertical range :

```
 ui->tableWidget_1->verticalScrollBar()->value();
```

for the first displayed row index (and it seems to works fine)

and

```
ui->tableWidget_1->verticalScrollBar()->pageStep();
```

for the total of rows displayed. But this last value doesn't work if the total number of rows is lower than this value.

Is there is another better option to achieve this ?

Thanks !